# What is the 'Boost' gauge used for?

Tags: hill-climb-racing

A lot of different cars have the 'RPM' gauge, which is fairly obvious that it acts similarly to an RPM gauge on a normal car. However, I have no idea what the 'Boost' gauge does - is there a certain boost that I can activate? Does it give me an advantage when it's full? I'm not sure what it does, since most of the time it matches the RPM gauge.

Here's a screenshot of the boost gauge, highlighted in pink:

[image: boost gauge]

Comment: An answer will be coming soon (hopefully)

Comment: what boost gauge are you talking about? Can you edit this post with a visual representation?

Comment: Done! Screenshot posted.

Comment: Ohh ok!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I emailed Fingersoft support and they replied with this:

> The boost gauge indicates the use of turbo on vehicle that have it.
>
> Sami-jukka Piippo (Fingersoft)

This means the boost gauge is different for each vehicle, simply displaying the level of turbo on that particular vehicle. For example the tank has a high boost (or turbo) according to the [Hill Climb Wiki](http://hillclimbracing.wikia.com/wiki/Tank), making the boost gauge max out at a high position. This is shown in this picture:

[image: Tank]

There is no boost that you can activate, nor does it give you an advantage when full. The boost gauge is accurate when at full RPM. The top boost can be affected by upgrades.